# Format a SwiftUI Textfield during editing (add thousands of separators)

Tags: swiftui, format, textfield, editing

I want to add thousands of separators to a text field while typing a number. My idea was to react to a onChange event, format the entered number and then write the formatted text into the text field:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TestFormatTextFieldView: View {
    @State private var stringAmount: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Amount", text: $stringAmount)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .onChange(of: stringAmount, perform: { newValue in
                        stringAmount = formatDouble(input: newValue)
                    })
                
                Button("Request price") {
                    self.requestPrice()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func formatDouble(input : String) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        
        // If the String can't be cast as a Double return ""
        guard let resultAsDouble = Double(input) else {
            return ""
        }
        
        let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: resultAsDouble)) ?? ""
        print("formatted \(result)")
        return result
    }
    
    func requestPrice() {
        print("request \(stringAmount)")
    }
}

struct TestFormatTextFieldView_Prev: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If I write more than 4 digits, I get the following error:
*onChange(of: String) action tried to update multiple times per frame.*
The problem is that formatting changes the length of the text. Is it still possible to add thousands of separators on the fly?

Comment: Why do you have to do the formatting yourself, why not make use of the built-in functionality?

Comment: The built-in formatter formats only after leaving the text field. However, I need formatting during editing (if possible).

Comment: Ok I understand but personally I don’t think it’s worth it, it’s hard to get it right for all situations and if it isn’t perfect it can be really annoying